# Launching Dash app with Batch file fails with Double click

Tags: batch-file, plotly-dash, double-click

I'm learning Dash and I'm trying to set up a small batch file to launch the app.

I'm using as an example the first app on this [plotly page](https://dash.plotly.com/layout). The app is very simple, and I included the code in a file called `smallapp.py`.

I use Anaconda as Python distribution, so I wrote a batch file called `launch_smallapp.bat` like this:

```
call C:\Users\Roberto\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
python C:\rob\Python\battest\smallapp.py
```

If I open a Command Prompt and type `launch_smallapp.bat`, the app starts correctly and I can visualise it at the url http://127.0.0.1:8050/

However, if I double-click the file `launch_smallapp.bat` the app doesn't work.

The Command Prompt shows the normal messages of the app being started, but if I visit the url the browser just says that the site can't be reached. 
[image: Command prompt on double-clicking .bat file]

The other thing is, the Command Prompt appears with a green frame.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you call `activate.bat`? I tried clicking a batch file with `python app.py` line, and it worked. (Python is in `PATH` and `dash` is installed in `base` virtual environment)

Comment: If I don't run `activate.bat` I get the message 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'. Isn't that supposed to happen? The error message is shown both on double-click and on launching the .bat file from command prompt

Comment: Here I see 2 possible problems. 1) You didn't install dash. You can install it with `pip install dash`. 2) Maybe you install it in a virtual environment. This is more possible. Then, you should activate the environment first, and it depends on what you use to manage virtual environments. As far as I understand, you use Anaconda. You should change the first line to `conda activate <your-virtual-env>`. Change <your-virtual-env> to your virtual environment name.

Comment: Thanks for your message.
1) If I run `pip install dash` the command window freezes. Something's wrong with my pip installation? 2) Dash was actually installed in a virtual environment. I use the `activate.bat` script to activate the base environment. If I just run `conda activate base` I get the message 'conda is not recognised'.

Comment: Freezing window while using `pip install`. I never had such a problem. Maybe something is wrong, as you say. I see your point now, and I don't know what causes your problem. I just can say that I use `call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate` on my computer, then `python app.py`, and it works. As you see, the only difference is the Anaconda installation path.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. When you double click the .bat file, does your command prompt show with a green border like mine? Maybe there is a hint in it?

Comment: You're welcome. No. There is no green border on the command prompt, it looks normal. Also, I give you an upvote. I hope somebody else can help.

Comment: Instead of using activating bat, try to directly use your environment python interpreter like this:
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\env_name\python.exe C:\rob\Python\battest\smallapp.py`. To check your interpreter path type in console: `where python`.

Comment: I have removed `activate.bat` and just left in the script `C:\Users\Roberto\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\rob\Python\battest\smallapp.py`. Again, the script works fine if I launch it in a command prompt, but not if I double click. Typing `where python` produces 3 different paths: `C:\Users\Roberto\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\Roberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
C:\Users\Roberto\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`
Is that normal?